# CSOM API how to find claims accounts unassociated with a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, groups

I'm trying to find claims accounts that are not associated with a site. These would be "{SiteName} Owners" and "{Site Name} Members" users that are automatically created in SharePoint Online when you create a site. The "{Site Name} Members" user is in the "{Site Name} Members" SharePoint group normally.

I'm trying to identify if its been removed from that group and then add it back. I just need a way to find the GUID for that user, which isn't in active directory.

I'm fairly new to SPFx development but so far I've only been able to query a site for associated users. Is there a way to find these users that are not associated with the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the SharePoint `Id` and `LoginName` of Office 365 group added inside SharePoint groups, use REST API in below format:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title,LoginName&$filter=Title eq 'SPConnect Members'
```

**Sample Response**:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7</d:Id>
    <d:LoginName>c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|68620d0f-babf-4685-90cb-5a0e4fee4065</d:LoginName>
    <d:Title>SPConnect Members</d:Title>
</m:properties>
```

You can use `Id` in response to grant/remove permissions from SharePoint site.

---

**Update from comments**:

When you create a O365 group connected team site, O365 group will be automatically added to Site Members group. At the same time, O365 group will added to hidden "User Information" list in site (can be accessed using URL: `<siteUrl>/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`).

The entry in this list will be preserved even when users manually remove O365 group from SharePoint permissions. So, you can always get the SharePoint ID of these groups using above API (no need to "EnsureUser" this group again in site).

You can use this ID directly to add the O365 group again to SharePoint group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isn't the use case I need. The Office 365 group in my case would be missing from the group. I am trying to find a way to find that group and add it back.

Comment: Are you creating team sites associated with O365?

Comment: Yes these would be teams sites, but users may have manually removed these groups from the SharePoint group, so they will not be associated anymore. I was trying to find a way to find these Office 365 Groups and add them back to the sites SharePoint group. I found a solution I just posted below.

Comment: When you create a O365 group connected team site, O365 group will be automatically added to Site Members group. At the same time, O365 will added to hidden "User Information" list in site (can be accessed using URL: `<siteUrl>/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`). The entry in this list will be preserved even when users manually remove O365 group from SharePoint permissions. So, you can always get the SharePoint ID of these groups using API give in my answer (no need to EnsureUser this group again in site). You can use this ID directly to add the O365 group again to SharePoint group.

Comment: Oh really? Ok thank you for that information!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to find the Office 365 group but I used the Graph API as well as CSOM.

```
var groups = await graphAPIAuth.Groups
.Request()
.Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
.Filter($"startswith(displayName, '{ctx.Web.Title}')")
.Top(1)
.GetAsync();

if (groups.Any())
{
      var group = groups.First();

      var user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser($"c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|{group.Id}");
      ctx.Load(user);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();

      var addUser = oGroup.Users.AddUser(user);
      ctx.Load(addUser);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```